# Is the TaskFactory attribute really optional in the <UsingTask> element?

Tags: xml, msbuild, msbuild-task

Is the `TaskFactory` attribute really optional in the `<UsingTask>` element ?

[**Microsoft's Documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/usingtask-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022) states that it is **optional**.

I played with the syntax of the `<UsingTask>` element but I could not come up with a case in which the `TaskFactory` attribute did not have to specified.

Below is the smallest snippet of code that will compile for me without errors:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="TestMe" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll" >
  <Task>
    <Code/>
  </Task>
</UsingTask>
```

My interest is academic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The `TaskFactory` is optional.

If you compile the `TestMe` task into an assembly named `TestMe.dll`, you can use `UsingTask` as follows:

```xml
  <UsingTask TaskName="TestMe" AssemblyFile="TestMe.dll" />
```

See "[Example 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/usingtask-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022#example-2)" in [**Microsoft's Documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/usingtask-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022).

Comment: I did not notice that when `<ParameterGroup>...` is specified that makes the `TaskFactory` attribute **mandatory**.

Comment: It works even if **nothing** related to the moniker `TestMe` is compiled into the DLL.

Comment: `AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll"` works as well.